# Namespace and Scope

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

The below code does not run:
It gives " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment"

```
p="hello"
def z():
    if p == "hello":
        p="2"
        print(p)
z()
```

But this code works, i am confused! in both cases i am assigning a variable inside a function.That should be local right?
The above code should also print 2 then.

```
p="hello"
def z():
    p="2"
    print(p)
z()
```

Output : "2"

and this also works

```
p="hello"
def z():
    if p == "hello":
        x="2"
        print(x)
z()
```

Output = 2

I am not expecting the local variable 'p' referenced before assignmen error.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a global variable because it was defined in the global scope.

To assign to a global variable from a non-global scope, such as in your function, you need to declare its usage with `global p` before using it.

For more information on the `global` keyword, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global.

Comment: I don't want to access the global variable. why it's not working when it is inside the if block? when it is there without the if statement it works. In both cases am I creating a local variable?

Comment: If you don't want to compare against the global variable `p`, what do you think the condition of the `if` statement is referring to?

Comment: Yes, that is right. It is checking the p variable defined in the gobal namespace as there is no local variable. But when there is no if statement p= "2" works. So when there is no if statement and p="2" that is assigning a local variable. but when the if statement is there, is it something different like I am checking the global variable so now it is trying to assign "2" to that global variable?

Comment: The status of `p` as a local or free variable is determined when the function is defined, not when the function is called. As long as *any* assignment to `p` exists in the body of the function, `p` is local for the *entire* function body. `global p` is what tells the function that `p` is always a global variable, not a free or local variable.

Comment: @chepner then why ```p="2"``` does not work when I use the if statement ```if p=="hello": ```

Comment: Because, as chepner explained, `p` is determined to be a local variable during the definition of `z`, so reading from it in the `if` statement condition is asking Python to read from a local variable before it is assigned.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. As ```p="2"``` is inside the function body. It is already in the local scope of that function. So when I am trying to check for the condition ```if p="hello" ``` it is raising an error : local variable 'p' referenced before assignment. As it is already in the local scope but not assigned yet cause it is inside the if block. Am i right?

Comment: yes got it. really appreciate it.  chepner  @thom747